# where condition in SQLite and EditText related Event

Tags: android, sqlite

Respected Users,
I am new with android and SQLite technology.
I am getting error in following statement.
Kindly correct me.

```
Cursor mCur=
    db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,
             new String[]{ROWID,MEDICINE,KEY_DESC,PRICE},
             MEDICINE+" = "+medName,null,null,null,null);
```

My Other question is that is there any event associated with EditText so that I can use its functionality as I was using it with `text_change` in C# .NET.
[When I types the text event should get fired].

For this I have tried with following events:

- setOnEditActionListener and
- setOnTouchListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In your SQL query I assume your `medName` was the problem because it is a String, use:

```
Cursor mCur=
    db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,
             new String[]{ROWID,MEDICINE,KEY_DESC,PRICE},
             MEDICINE+" = ?",new String[] {medName},null,null,null);
```

This approach also protects you from SQL injection attacks.

2) To listen for changes in an EditText, use a [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

```
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Cursor mCur=
    db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,
             new String[]{ROWID,MEDICINE,KEY_DESC,PRICE},
             MEDICINE+" like % ? %",new String[] {medName},null,null,null);

Comment: Close, but no. Add the wildcards directly to your String: `MEDICINE+" like ?",new String[] {"%"+medName+"%"}`

Answer (score 0):

For your Sqlite question please post the Logcat logs.

Add a TextWatcher to your EditText to implement 3 callback methods.